# Retrieve all site collections

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, site-collection, visual-studio-2013

I want to retrieve all site collections in an Online tenant through Visual Studio:

- I can do it via Powershell: `get-sposite`
- on-premise server : `Get-SPSite`
- on-premise again: `var sites = webapp.Sites.Where(i=>i.url.StartsWith(webapp.url + "/departments/"));  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7137/how-can-i-list-the-site-collections-under-a-given-url-path`

I can use the following code to iterate through sites within **one** site collection, so I thought I could try "https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/" but of course it doesn't work, because such site doesn't exist.

> "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." at context.ExecuteQuery():

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/);
            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName2, password2);

            Web site = context.Web;

            context.Load(context.Web.Webs);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            string allsitecollections = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < context.Web.Webs.Count; i++)
            {

                allsitecollections = allsitecollections + context.Web.Webs[i].Url + "\n";

            }
```

Is there a way to retrieve the site collections with C# or should I resort to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c.aspx ?

Comment: online tenant? Do we know the WebApplication?

Comment: @VarunVerma Webapplications is not really a thing visible to the tenants in Office 365 SharePoint Online

Comment: @RobertLindgren okiz :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it all from C# using the excellent post found [here](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2014-4-Get_list_of_site_collections_using_CSOM_in_Office365.aspx).

This example is, I believe, from within a SharePoint app but you can do it similarly from a console app.

First you'll need to add a reference to Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll which you can find here (C:\Program Files\SharePoint Client Components\Assemblies) after installing the [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=35585).

The only real difference in the code is how you create your ClientContext and pass credentials. Here is a full example:

```
siteUrl = "https://yourtenantname-admin.sharepoint.com";
userName = "you@company.com";
password = "password";

using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, passWord);

    var tenant = new Tenant(clientContext);
    SPOSitePropertiesEnumerable spp = tenant.GetSiteProperties(0, true);

    clientContext.Load(spp);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (SiteProperties sp in spp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sp.Title);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By using

```
SPOSitePropertiesEnumerable spp = tenant.GetSiteProperties(0, true);
```

you will get limited to 300 site collections only.

I shared my solution here to get all the site collections here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405584/sharepoint-csom-retrieving-site-collections-limited-to-300/24406495?noredirect=1#comment40072226_24406495

```
SPOSitePropertiesEnumerable spp = null;
var tenant = new Tenant(ctx);
int startIndex = 0;

while (spp == null || spp.Count > 0)
{
    spp = tenant.GetSiteProperties(startIndex, true);
    ctx.Load(spp);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (SiteProperties sp in spp)
    siteCols.Add(new SiteCol(sp.Title, sp.Url));

    startIndex = siteCols.Count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to resort to calling the PowerShell, and using the `Get-SPOSite` cmdlet to get all the site collections.

The following will return the url of all site collections:

```
var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();
var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Commands.AddScript( "Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell" );

pipeline.Commands.AddScript( "$password = \"" + password + "\"" +
                             " | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force" );
pipeline.Commands.AddScript( "$spoCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential(\"" +
                             userName + "\", $password)" );

pipeline.Commands.AddScript( "Connect-SPOService -Url " + adminUrl + " -Credential $spoCreds" );

pipeline.Commands.AddScript( "Get-SPOSite" );
var results = pipeline.Invoke();
runspace.Close();
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach ( var psObject in results )
{
    var site = psObject.Members["Url"];

    stringBuilder.AppendLine( site.Value.ToString() );
}
Console.WriteLine( stringBuilder.ToString() );
```

I had no idea what I was doing when I originally wrote this, so it can probably be done better.

Answer (score 0):

tenant.GetSiteProperties(startIndex, true); will only return classic sites. To return modern sites, you can utilize the Office PnP GetSiteCollections method.

```
var tenant = new Tenant(ctx);
var sites = tenant.GetSiteCollections(0, 5000, true);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```