# SharePoint 2013 Online Search Query for Site Collections

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I wonder if It's possible to get all my site collection names or paths in Javascript, Visual Studios. I've found them through REST when I put 
`server/_api/search/query?querytext='sharepoint'`
 in the adressbar in Internet Explorer. I'm using SharePoint Online in Office 365. But how do I do it code wise in Javascript. I've tried some examples but none have worked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and did not work?

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105653/retrieve-all-site-collections/105710#105710

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work so I will share my victory with you.
This code works if you need to get the Site collections paths, title etc.

```
var queryUrl = spAppWebUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='sharepoint'&trimduplicates=false&rowlimit=400&refinementfilters='contentclass:equals("STS_Site")'

 $.ajax({ url: queryUrl, method: "GET", headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }, success: onQuerySuccess, error: onQueryError });
    });

function onQuerySuccess(data) {
var results = data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results;

$("#resultsDiv").append('<table>');

$.each(results, function () {
    $("#resultsDiv").append('<tr>');
    $.each(this.Cells.results, function () {



        if (this.Key == "Title") {

            $("#resultsDiv").append('<td>' + this.Value + '</td>');
        }
        if (this.Key == "Path") {
            $("#resultsDiv").append('<td>' + this.Value + '</td>');
        }

    });
    $("#resultsDiv").append('</tr>');
});
$("#resultsDiv").append('</table>');}
```