# List all site collection in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, office-365

I want to retrieve all site collection from my webpart. i have code to get all site collection which is work in on premise.

```
SPWebApplication webApplication = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication;
        SPSiteCollection siteCollections = webApplication.Sites;

        foreach (SPSite siteCollection in siteCollections)
        {
            ddlsubsite0.Items.Add(new ListItem(siteCollection.RootWeb.Title, siteCollection.ServerRelativeUrl));
        }
```

but as we used SPWebApplication, it is not working in Office 365.

Comment: Check this thread : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105653/retrieve-all-site-collections

Comment: ClientContext is also not working in Office 365. it is for client side application

Comment: Is it possible to do it using powershell or it should be in C# ?

Comment: c#. i want to list all site collection in webpart in office365

Comment: Before marking as duplicate question, please read question exactly. The question asked previously is for client side solution and my question is for  office 365 webpart.

Comment: An Office 365 "webpart" would need to use the client object model since you can not run server side code in Office 365