# Get SP online site content via PowerShell or C# (for BackUp SharePoint Online Site content into local storage)

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, powershell, backup, library

I need to BackUp SharePoint Online Site content into local storage. I know there is no tools for it (for SharePoint Online version). I want to write my own tool that will copy all site content to a local drive (library to some archive, lists to excel file). I have about 15 SP sites which I need to backup. I know that MS stores data every 14 days on it's services, but this is not enough.

I plan to write a powershell script or programm in C#. But I can't get to site content programmatically.

How can I get content from site library or a list by PowerShell or C# in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 1):

For now this is what I get from another forum:
 For working with SPO we need [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=35585). After that we can start to work with SPO, [exsample](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105653/retrieve-all-site-collections) to get context, and get all properties of site:

```
siteUrl = "https://yourtenantname-admin.sharepoint.com";
userName = "you@company.com";
password = "password";

using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, passWord);

    var tenant = new Tenant(clientContext);
    SPOSitePropertiesEnumerable spp = tenant.GetSiteProperties(0, true);

    clientContext.Load(spp);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (SiteProperties sp in spp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sp.Title);
    }
}
```

[More samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx) work with SPO context.